# disallowed field type array - How to create array in aggregation with MongoDBv3.0

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My document structure is,

```
{
    _id : '',
    objects: {
        dyn1: {
            prop1: val1,
            prop2: val2
        },
        dyn2: {
            prop1: val1,
            prop2: val2
        },
        dyn3: {
            prop1: val1,
            prop2: val2
        }
    }
}
```

I want to do the search, sort, limit on inner-object of `objects`. I found a solution that works with MongoDBv3.2. The first step I need to do is making each inner-object a part of the separate document. `$unwind` can help us, but it will work only with arrays. So, my first stage was to project as array,

```
{
    $project: {
         asArray: [
            '$objects.dyn1',
            '$objects.dyn2',
            '$objects.dyn3'
        ]
    }
}
```

The creation of arrays is working well in MongoDBv3.2. But with MongoDBv3.0, it is throwing the following error:

`exception: disallowed field type Array in object expression MongoDB aggregation array.`

How to avoid this error and project values as an array in MongoDBv3.0? Is there any workaround possible?

Comment: Isn't Objects an array?

Comment: No @israel.zinc Objects is not an array

Comment: So, Objects is an object that contains 3 other objects as fields: dyn1, dyn2, dyn3? So, which parameter you use to sort fields?

Comment: I will use `prop1` or `prop2` to sort them. If said `prop1`  less than 10, the query should return all inner-objects of which `prop1` satisfies the condition. Likewise sort, skip, limit all can be applied